# How to see several types/kind of values in a particular column in linux?

Tags: linux, types, kind

I have a .txt file in linux (with 56 columns and 18000 rows) named 'file1.txt' with the data that looks like this;

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   2   3   4   5
2   3   0   0   0   0
3   4   1   1   1   1
0.008   0   2   0.008   0   2
1.999   1   0   1.999   1   0.001
0.04    2   1   0.04    2   4
0   0.001   2   0   0   3
1   1   0   5   0   0.008
2   2   0.013   0.008   1   1.999
0   0.999   0   1.999   1.99    0.04
0   2   1   1.758   0   1
1   1.999   2   0.002   2   1
1.99    1.999   2   0.003   1.99    0
0   1.999   1   10  0   9
```

Question: How do I see several kind/types of values a particular column has? For example, I want to see that in column C3 how many kind of values are there like a list of 0, 1,2,3,0.013 and so on).

Comment: `cut -f3 file1.txt` if the fields are tab separated.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Is there a way that values in the output list won't repeat? I mean if the C3 have 1, it should appear only once in the list!

Comment: `cut -f3 data.txt | sort -k3 | uniq` if the fields are tab separated. But this gives a sorted output (the order of printed lines may be different than that of the original file).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you, it worked